Base representations, using only limited digits
Recently I saw this sequence problem from Scientific American. Given the terms below, find the next three:
$110, 20, 12, 11, 10, 6, ...$
As many readers probably figured out more quickly than I, the answer is all the terms are actually the same number, six, represented in base two, then base three, and so on. When the base number exceeds six, of course, the representation collapses to the single digit $6$ and this then becomes all the subsequent terms.
I note that before we reach the single digit point, all the preceding representations use digits considerably smaller than the chosen number value (here, six). So we might suppose that six could be replaced by a number $N$ greater than ten and yet we could still use only the standard digits $0$ through $9$ in the multi-digit representations up to base $N$ (we would still have to define a symbol for $N$ itself when the base is $N+1$ or more). So:
What is the largest natural number $N$ whose base representations from base two through base $N$ use only the digits $0$ through $9$?
The mathematical calculation required to score the solution is quite simple; the hard part is finding out where to look for it. The reader might take another look at how small the digits in the first five terms are in the Scientific American puzzle, compared with the original $N=6$ value.

This question can be reduced to finding the greatest natural number $N$ such that $N \text{ mod } b < 11$ for all natural numbers $b$ from $2$ to $N$. Edit: I think I’m wrong actually

Not quite $<11$.

Firstly

 If $N > 20$ then writing $N$ in base $b = N-10$ gives $1a$ where we use the digit $a$ to represent "ten".

Secondly

 For $N=20$, the sequence of representations of $N$ in bases from $2$ to $N$ are $10100, 202, 110, 40, 32, 26, 24, 22, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10$ so we have our answer.

Answer

 $N=20$

Hint in the question

 "The mathematical calculation required to score the solution is quite simple" (thanks OP).


You "scored"! Did you catch my use of that word in the problem statement?

@OscarLanzi Actually I missed that first time, d'oh! Very clever.

If any number $>2$ requires multiple digits to represent it in a given base, then the digits used in that representation are less than half the number. So $20$ whose half is only $10$ must work.
